# Upload Image in facebook graph api by codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I have made facebook app before also without codeigniter but this time facing little problem in integrating it with codeigniter.
But finally I did it. But I am unable to upload images to a particular album in user's profile. I am getting this error message -->

```
Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 26: failed creating formpost data thrown in facebook.php on line
```

Someone please help me in that.

Here is the code--->

```
$base_url = base_url();
            $image_name = $this->common_model->fetch_image_name_by_id($image_id);
$fb_config = array(
            'appId'  => '148056051963323',
            'secret' => '0cebf087b3084e5a772b6c31acb2736a'  
        );

    $this->load->library('facebook', $fb_config);
$this->facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
                $album_details = array(
                    'message'=> 'Win Free T-shirts',
                    'name'=> 'LoL Sharing'
                );
            $create_album = $this->facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);


            $photo_details = array(
                'message'=> 'photo description'
            );
            $photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath(''.$base_url.'assets/joke_images/'.$image_name['image_name'].'');
            $upload_photo = $this->facebook->api('/'.$create_album['id'].'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use base_url() with realpath(). You need an absolute path to the image file to complete the upload.

```
$photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath(''.$base_url.'assets/joke_images/'.$image_name['image_name'].'');
```

Good luck

Edit: With codeigniter I usually use FCPATH for paths. FCPATH.'assets/joke_images'...

Comment: thanks a lot....but i tried using relative path also but it is not working with that too :(

Comment: How about this: FCPATH.assets/joke_images/'.$image_name['image_name']
  (If assets is in the root folder).